# HTML file not being linked to css file

Tags: html, css

Okay, so i just made a landing page for a website and its working perfectly fine. But the only problem is that the css of a certain element [button :p] is not working. I checked all the brackets and the semicolons but didn't find any errors. any help would be appreciated.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      event.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){
           window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } 
  });
});
</script>
    <title>Versatile | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="navbar">
        <h3>Versatile</h3>
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#About">About</a>
        <a href="#Products">Our Alliances and Products</a>
        <a href="#Registered">Get Registered</a>
        <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div id="home">
        <h3>Versatile Infosecurity Pvt. Ltd.</h3>
        <button href="#About">Explore</button>
    </div>
    <div id="About">
        <h3>About</h3>
        <p>Versatile Infosecurity Pvt., Ltd. has tied up with some of the worldwide leaders in network security to occupy a
leading position in offering customers end-to- end solutions in enterprise-wide security. We have been dedicated
to serving the needs of the antivirus and security community. Through constant innovations and strategic tie-
ups, Versatile Infosecurity offers many services and solutions, sourced from the Leading Manufacturers the
world over that address key areas in the deployment of software based security and management systems. We
offer specialized services in Antivirus, Network Management and Network security area.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Products">
        <h3>Our Alliances and Products</h3>
        <div class="card-conatiner">
<div class="card">
    <img src="images/a10networks.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
    <hr>
<div class="container">
    <center>
    <h4>A10 Networks</h4>
    <br><br>
    <button class="btn" href="a10networks.com">Visit Website</button>
</center>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.css**

```
body {
    background-image: url('images/bodybackground.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
#navbar {
    background: transparent;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 10px;
}
#navbar h3 {
    color: white;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
#navbar h3:hover {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
#navbar a {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
}
#navbar a:hover {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: orange;
}
#home {
    margin-top: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}
#home button{
    padding: 10px 40px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
}
#home button:hover {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 60px;
}
#home h3 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#About {
    height: 500px;
    background: white;
}
#About h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#About p {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 20px;
}
#Products {
    height: 1000px;
    background: lightgrey;
    padding: 10px;
}
#Products h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#Products .a10 {
    margin: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url('images/a10networks.jpg');
}
.btn {
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: black;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
}
.btn:hover {
    background: black;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: white;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
}
.card {
        box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        margin-left: : 50px;
        background: white;
    }
    .card:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
    }
    .card-container {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
    .card-container h4 {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

**PS**
Please help fast
and also tell me how the site is looking. It is my first official project.

Comment: You have an extra closing </div> tag, and I don't see that class in your css.

Comment: <button href="#About">Explore</button> This do not have class 'btn' which is defined in your CSS. It should be as follows:
<button href="#About" class="btn">Explore</button>

Comment: you have double colon `.card {
        margin-left: : 50px;
      
    }` and extra closing `</div>` before the body closing tag

Answer (score 0):

You're using one extra closing  tag, `margin-left: : 50px;` is not correct and your code format is wrong. Use TAB button to align your code.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").on('click', function(event) {
        if (this.hash !== "") {
            event.preventDefault();
            var hash = this.hash;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 800, function(){
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        } 
    });
});
</script>
    <title>Versatile | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="navbar">
        <h3>Versatile</h3>
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#About">About</a>
        <a href="#Products">Our Alliances and Products</a>
        <a href="#Registered">Get Registered</a>
        <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div id="home">
        <h3>Versatile Infosecurity Pvt. Ltd.</h3>
        <button href="#About">Explore</button>
    </div>
    <div id="About">
        <h3>About</h3>
        <p>Versatile Infosecurity Pvt., Ltd. has tied up with some of the worldwide leaders in network security to occupy a
leading position in offering customers end-to- end solutions in enterprise-wide security. We have been dedicated
to serving the needs of the antivirus and security community. Through constant innovations and strategic tie-
ups, Versatile Infosecurity offers many services and solutions, sourced from the Leading Manufacturers the
world over that address key areas in the deployment of software based security and management systems. We
offer specialized services in Antivirus, Network Management and Network security area.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Products">
        <h3>Our Alliances and Products</h3>
        <div class="card-conatiner">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="images/a10networks.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
        <hr>
    <div class="container">
    <center>
        <h4>A10 Networks</h4>
        <br><br>
        <button class="btn" href="a10networks.com">Visit Website</button>
    </center>
    </div></div></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-image: url('images/bodybackground.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
#navbar {
    background: transparent;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 10px;
}
#navbar h3 {
    color: white;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
#navbar h3:hover {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
#navbar a {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
}
#navbar a:hover {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: orange;
}
#home {
    margin-top: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}
#home button {
    padding: 10px 40px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
}
#home button:hover {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 60px;
}
#home h3 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#About {
    height: 500px;
    background: white;
}
#About h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#About p {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 20px;
}
#Products {
    height: 1000px;
    background: lightgrey;
    padding: 10px;
}
#Products h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#Products .a10 {
    margin: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url('images/a10networks.jpg');
}
.btn {
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: black;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
}
.btn:hover {
    background: black;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: white;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
}
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background: white;
}
.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.card-container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.card-container h4 {
     text-align: center;
}
```

See if it works now. If not, please provide a direct link to the images used.
You may want to also explain how this button is supposed to behave or explain what's wrong with it.